# The aggregate function showing error "No Rows to aggregate"

Tags: r

code source :https://aschinchon.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/how-do-cities-feel/
I'm trying to execute the code from the above link but it is giving me following error:

```
df1=aggregate(cities.scores["score"], by=cities.scores[c("CITY")], FUN=length)
```

> Error in `aggregate.data.frame(cities.scores["score"], by = cities.scores[c("CITY")],`  : 
>     no rows to aggregate

Comment: Please check the `str(cities.scores)`

Comment: @code_r Please check your data do it has rows as R shoots an error saying no rows to aggregate

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh that's the probelm. its not creating rows for aggregate fucntion.